# How validate a control form in angular 13?

Tags: typescript, angular13

I have a ractive form in angular 13 dedined like that:
[image]

So I want to validate this form like that:
[image]

I get the following error:
[image]

and
[image]

noting that in the component I have a get function like:

```
  get firstname() {
    return this.myGroup.get('firstname');
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template is wrong.

```
<div *ngIf="firstname?.errors?.['required']">First name is required</div>
```

Comment: Why we need to add ? after firstname and errors?